# Getting regression coefficients in terms of original variables using principal component regression

Tags: r, regression, pca

I'm trying to understand Principal Component Regression(PCR) using dummy data (no multicollinearity). I have managed to regress dependent variable on scores but how do I convert the coefficients back to coefficients of original independent data? Below is my example using R

```
# create dummy data for testing
a1<-1:10
a2<-rnorm(10,0,5)  # uncorrelated to a1, for testing purposes
a<-cbind(a1,a2)
y<-a1-2*a2   # dependent variable

pr<-princomp(a,cor=TRUE)
s<-pr$scores
m2<-lm(y~s)

# results
m2$coefficients 
(Intercept)     sComp.1     sComp.2 
 2.461620   -7.370569  -11.432588
```

**How do I convert `m2$coefficients` back to coefficients in terms of original data?**

From what I have learned so far, I only need to multiply EigenVectors with the above coefficients. But the coefficients have dimension of 3x1 and eigenvectors are 2x2!

Comment: Note that the Intercept term is independent of the PCs/original variables. It's the other coefficients that you need to associate with the eigenvectors.

Comment: @EdM Thank you for your reply, I multiplied the coefficient of scores with eigen vectors but the results look very different from 1 and -2. Which is what they should be given there is little multicollinearity. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Post the code you used to do the multiplication of coefficients by the eigenvectors and the results; show the eigenvectors too. For reproducing your results, it helps to set (and report) the seed for the random number generator before the rnorm() command. I have a hunch that this has to do with centering and normalizing (or not) the data before the PCA.

Comment: @user2696565, please do as EdM suggested in their last comment if you want this question to be resolved.

Comment: @EdM Thank you for your help, I should have replied earlier that it is now resolved. The solution was your first comment - that the intercept term s independent. I had a bug in my code when I wrote my previous comment.